# how to downgrade from kernal 6.5 to 6.2 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, realtek-wireless, downgrade

please how do i downgrade from kernel 6.5 to 6.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.
this is to help resolve WIFI persistent disconnection

Comment: Under the "Advanced"  grub menu item, you should have a series of older kernels for booting.  Do you have gcc-12 installed on your machine, that may be all it takes to fix your problems, so the module can build for the 6.5 kernel.

Comment: Thank you @ubfan1 for your response, i ran the command to know the version of gcc i have, i saw  it to be "gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)".
As for the grub menu, i can only see 6.4 as the former.

Comment: The 6.2 kernel came from [Ubuntu 23.04 which is EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/), thus you won't be getting security patches if using it on 22.04 meaning you should remain off-line. The safest option is the switch to the GA kernel stack (5.15) which receives security patches for the life of 22.04 LTS (*it was the default stack for many 22.04 media inc. flavors & Server*) OR use the current HWE kernel.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: You mention seeing 6.4 as a former kernel??  That isn't a supported kernel option for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, are you using Ubuntu?  If you are you've altered your system, as 5.15 was GA, 5.19 was .2 kernel, 6.2 the .3 kernel & 6.5 the .4 kernel (22.04.4 changes have been rolling out near two weeks now!) with only other OEM options available; you've not mention OEM details though. Your system details are *unclear* if you're using a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system.

Comment: @guiverc, please I just completed the downgrade before seeing your message about the security threat are I'm open to... Should I upgrade it to the 6.5.15 version.

Comment: @guiverc, yes if my memory can serve me right, except I wasn't sure of what I have been seeing, it's 6.4...

Comment: Please this issue is seriously making me loose sleep... Even while booting to Windows 10, the WiFi issues still persist

Comment: If you're using a 6.4 kernel you're likely not using a Ubuntu *supported* kernel IF you're using a Ubuntu (I'm ignoring OEM kernel options as you don't mention OEM which is shown clearly in `uname` output in my view) which means it was only ever packaged for *testing* purposes & has no security patches are provided by Ubuntu.  If you're capable of backporting the security patches yourself, then for sure you may use it. The safest options are always GA (5.15 for 22.04; default for Server & some *flavor* ISOs) or HWE (*which changes to newer kernels from later releases*)..

Comment: I can was seeing from the grub menu that option there, that is 6.4, but I can't any longer, since installing 6.2...

Comment: Seriously, I am not a heavy user of Linux, I plan to be, but not now. All I want Is to fix my WiFi issues that's all

Comment: Whichever version that threatens my learning, I don't want it... I have tried a lot of things to fix this, no heads way

Comment: @ubfan1, i just installed gcc-12, and nothing positive has happened, still disconnecting

Comment: Please add additional information to your original posting, comments may be deleted at some point.  Both Windows and Ubuntu wifi problems may indicate a hardware issue -- anywhere from a switch to toggle wifi to a loose antenna connection. You may check that the wifi module exists and used the correct compiler (gcc-12 for the 6.5 kernel, gcc-11 for the 5.15). Look in /lib/modules/<kernel>, e.g. /lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi  for the intel wifi, yours may be different. strings x.ko |grep -i gcc for the gcc version.

Answer (score -1):

first install the mainline ppa

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:cappelikan/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo apt install mainline
```

then open it, Select an earlier version of the Linux kernel and click Install. Then restart

Comment: Alright sir, thank you very much, i will inform you of the outcome

Comment: It was successful, however it didn't solve my problem. Thank you